# Zeta Function In Real And Imaginary Parts

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta

The zeta function is defined for a complex input $s$:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}$$

What I am wondering is if there are functions $f$ and $g$ such that:

$$\zeta(s) = f(s) + ig(s)$$

By using simple algebra on the Dirichlet series you can show that the real and imaginary components are separable into the form:

$$\zeta(\sigma + it) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t\ln(n))}{n^\sigma} - i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t\ln(n))}{n^\sigma}$$

Are there any other functions like this? Can you separate the real and imaginary components on other definitions of the zeta function? Like the Hurwitz or other representations? Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: interesting splitting, but $n^s$ in the complex field is a multivalued function and don't know if choosing the principal branch holds for the analytical continuation as well. Wish others more expert may clarify this point.

Comment: Can you explain how you got your representation above. I know of a similar representation that is valid for $0\le\sigma\le 1$. I might post this as an answer. It is not known, to my knowledge.

Comment: @EGME Just write $\frac{1}{n^s}=\mathrm{exp}\left(\ln\frac{1}{n^{s}}\right)$ and go from there.

Comment: Thanks. I will ping you if I post something about a similar representation that works for a larger domain.

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution to your problem. There are other series representations of $\zeta$ which allow you to separate real and imaginary parts as you have done. I can post them; unlike the solution I posted, they are not approximations, but exact.; of course, they are not as simple as what I have posted below. I think the solution I posted is probably the best in terms of simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

For any set $X$ and any function $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$, you can simply define $g,h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x)=\mathrm{Re}(f(x))\qquad h(x)=\mathrm{Im}(f(x))$$
and then you have $f(x)=g(x)+ih(x)$ for all $x$. Whether or not these functions have any interesting properties is another matter.

By the way, the equality $\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$ is ***only*** true for complex numbers $s$ with $\mathrm{Re}(s)>1$. It is not a correct statement for other choices of $s$, the only correct definition is with analytic continuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hardy and Littlewood’s approximation (see Titchmarsh, Theorem 4.11), which is valid for $\sigma>0$:

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\le x}\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}+O(x^{-\sigma}).$$

If you let $x=t$ (something the conditions of the cited theorem allows you to do), you can combine the second term with the error term to get an error term of $O(t^{-\sigma}+it^{-\sigma})$, unless I have made a mistake in my calculations. Now you can expand the summation in the same way that you expanded it for the Dirichlet series.